# export animation for gltf

Tags: animation, gltf

I've created a simple model with animation following this tuto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqJK4JxOZJs

but when I exported this into gltf + bin + texture, I can't find the animations field in the .gltf file.

when I exported the model the animations is already checked and i checked the Apply Modifiers.

am I missing something?

I want a gltf file that contains something like that but generated with blender

```
"animations": [
    {
      "channels": [
        {
          "sampler": 0,
          "target": {
            "node": 0,
            "path": "weights"
          }
        }
      ],
      "samplers": [
        {
          "input": 10,
          "interpolation": "LINEAR",
          "output": 11
        }
      ],
      "name": "Square"
    }
  ]
```

thank you

Comment: Can this link help you? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html  See if  "glTF Separate (.gltf + .bin + textures)" help you in the link above.

Comment: Try selecting to sphere and picking _Object > Animation > Bake Action_ from the 3D View.

Comment: @8NFilms, yes i've already took a look but can't help me to extract the animations

Comment: @scurest I did it