# how to export animation as gltf format

Tags: animation, gltf

I made a simple animated model under blender but when I exported it as gltf, the animations don't come in the file.

how to solve this?

Comment: Hello. You'll need to provide more details, maybe a screenshot. What did you animate?

Comment: a bouncing ball, and when I export it to gltf and open the gltf file, there's no attribute ```animations```

Comment: How did you animate it? Keyframes on its Location?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqJK4JxOZJs I have followed this tuto

Comment: Oh, someone else [asked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218483/export-animation-for-gltf) about that too. Try selecting to sphere and picking _Object > Animation > Bake Action_ from the 3D View.

Comment: I did it, as in the tuto no?

Comment: No, but actually it wouldn't work anyway. The softbody animation changes the locations of individual tris in the mesh. glTF only supports animations that change the location of the whole object.

Comment: how to do then?

Comment: For a softbody animation, it'd be pretty complicated. A rigid body animation would be a lot easier; just use _Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes_.

Comment: there's no Bake toKeyframes

Comment: Select _Object_ in the 3D View (near the _Add_ for adding cubes and stuff), then _Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes_. The object you want to bake needs to be selected and in Object mode.